# Invalid operands 'bool' and 'float' in operator '<' when comparing floats in gdscript

Tags: comparison-operators, godot, gdscript

I am using Godot 3.2.1 and I am making a turret scene, which rotates and shoots when it's pointing at a player. `rotation` is a property of `Area2D` and `target_dir` is the value of rotation which points at the player. I want the turret to shoot when these values are equal to each other plus-minus 0.1 uncertainty

```py
if target_dir - 0.1 < rotation < target_dir + 0.1:  # this line has error
    print("bang!!!")
    if can_shoot:
        shoot()
```

The application fails immediately after running it. When I printed `position` and `target_dir` they were both floats, though the error states

```
Invalid operands 'bool' and 'float' in operator '<'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Godot language has a lot of common with Python, The syntax like `a < b < c` would be OK for Python, but not for GDScript. Godot language probably "sees" the if-statement like this

```py
 if (target_dir - 0.1 < rotation) < target_dir + 0.1:
    ...
```

It does comparisons one by one and the result of the first operation has a boolean type. Hence the second operation compares bool with float and error occurs. So instead I used `and` keyword and two comparisons.

```py
if target_dir - 0.1 < rotation and rotation < target_dir + 0.1:
    print("bang!!!")
    if can_shoot:
        shoot()
```